# Validation multiple text fields MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I want to do the validation of multiple text fields

**Values ​​must be between 0 and @ViewBag.MaxNote**

In the view I have the following:

```
@model IList<RolesMVC3.Models.STUDENTS>
<P>Please enter a value between 0 and : @ViewBag.MaxNote<P>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
{

  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
          @Html.TextBox("txt")
    }
 <input type="submit" value="type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" /> 
}
```

I have to validate the field depending on the value of "@ViewBag.MaxNote"

How I can do this?

Comment: Could you explain it little more

Comment: @Shyju Please view edit, the text in bold :)